# null pointer exception at getRingerMode()

Tags: java, android, android-studio, debugging

I wrote this app where users can toggle silent mode by clicking on an image button:
    package p.a;

```
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView imageView;
    AudioManager audioManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        final AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
        View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mode.toggle(audioManager);
                update();
            }
        };
        imageView.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    }

    public void update(){
        int mod=mode.phonesilent(audioManager)?
                R.drawable.ringer_off:
                R.drawable.ringer_on;
        }
    }
```

Here's the mode class:

```
package p.a;

import android.media.AudioManager;

/**
 * Created by root on 9/19/17.
 */

public class mode {
    public static boolean phonesilent(AudioManager audioManager){
        return audioManager.getRingerMode()==AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT;
    }

    public static void toggle(AudioManager audioManager){
        int mode = phonesilent(audioManager)?
                AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL:
                AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT;
    }
}
```

The app can be initialized normally, but when I click on the image icon, it crashes and produces the error message in the title.
Here's the logcat:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.media.AudioManager.getRingerMode()' on a null object reference
                                                         at p.a.mode.phonesilent(mode.java:11)
                                                         at p.a.MainActivity.update(MainActivity.java:29)
                                                         at p.a.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:22)
```

Comment: Just change `final AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);` to `audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);` because you have already declared  `AudioManager audioManager;` in declaration part.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly create a Mode Object like this :

```
Mode mode = new Mode();
```

Comment: But all the methods in the mode class are static, so you don't need to create an instance of it order to invoke them.

Comment: No need to create instance because class has static methods.

Comment: Do you know what causes this problem to arise?

Comment: @Piyush I'm going deeper here. Why does this error occur when you add a type modifier in front? Of course I've already declared it before oncreate method, but why would adding its type cause that particular problem?

Comment: @pxc3110 Ok so what you want to know ?

Comment: @Piyush Which part of that do you not get? You want me to repeat?

Comment: @Piyush Why would adding a type modifier in front cause a nullpointer exception? You only told me to remove it, but really didn't tell me anything about the underlying mechanics that causes that problem.

Comment: That because you are using two objects of audioManager from which is null.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as Vamshi Krishna says, it's totally a good answer for this problem, but if you don't want to instantiate it for some reason you could change "Mode class" to a "Mode static class" as follows:

```
package p.a;

import android.media.AudioManager;

/**
 * Created by root on 9/19/17.
 */

public static class mode {
    public static boolean phonesilent(AudioManager audioManager){
        return audioManager.getRingerMode()==AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT;
    }
    public static void toggle(AudioManager audioManager){
        int mode = phonesilent(audioManager)?
                AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL:
                AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: No need to change class though. Because error doesn't relate to this.

Comment: @Óscar García Sáez it says 'Modifier static not allowed here', why is that?

Comment: @pxc3110 But why are you going to deep? I have already commented . Check it. It will solve your issue.

Comment: Sorry, I'm responding to Óscar García Sáez's answer

Comment: Yes. But that is not your solution @pxc3110

Comment: @pxc3110 Hmm, it's weird, here I can't test it in android studio because I don't have it installed but it seems that you have to create an static class within a class to be able to make it static as it says in this webpage that i looked up: https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/java-static-class-example/

So you can give it a try creating an outer dummy class, you can try it and tell if it works, if it gives you another nullPointer, maybe Piyush is right

Comment: @ÓscarGarcíaSáez Your answer isn't relevant to the real cause of this problem. I do wonder what really causes this exception though.